# Can you use vi with multiple file names specified on command line?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to specify multiple file names on the command line when starting vi?

Answer (score 5):

Yep just use :n to go to the next file in the list, and :N to go to the previous.

Comment: thanks...one other things 
in vi "y5w" yanks five words from cursor position?

Answer (score 1):

You can open multiple files by using globbing E.g., `vi *.html` will open all the HTML files in your current directory.  And, as Alex says in his answer, you can navigate back and forth through the files with `:n` and `:N`.

If you want to open multiple files *at the same time*, you can also use the split command.

Open the first file as usual, then, then use the command `:split yourfile.ext`

You should now see both files at the same time in a split-screen view.  You can do this with more than 2 files (but I'm not sure what the limit is).

Now, you can navigate between the windows with `ctrl-w` and the arrow keys.  So, if you're in the bottom pane, and you want your cursor in the upper pane, you'd first press `ctrl-w`, then press the `up-arrow` key.

Also, you can resize one of the panes by adding or subtracting rows/lines in that view.  So if you're in the upper pane and you want it to be 5 lines larger, you'd press `5`, then `ctrl-w`, then `+`.  Same for reducing with the `-` key.

I'm sure that there are many other commands you can use, but these are the ones I use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Also convenient:

```
vim -p file1 file2 file3
```

That will open up vim with tabs containing each file specified. You can jump between files with

```
gt
```

and

```
gT
```

If you do

```
:set mouse=a
```

you can also click on the tabs to open or drag them (although hardcore vim users would frown on this :) )